# Find a Certain Cell based on other Cells in Excel/Calc

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet:

```
Beans       B-kg        Chips       C-kg
1.4oz/12    0.47544     6.5oz/20    3.679
1.48oz/12   0.502608    7oz/12      2.3772
1.86oz/12   0.631656    8oz/20      4.528
```

and a second sheet:

```
Category Name       Case Kg
Beans   1.4oz/12    ?
Beans   1.48oz/12   ?
Chips   6.5oz/20    ?
```

I am trying to match the type of product with the correct weight. So I need a formula that will choose the correct column based on the Category and then choose the correct row based on the name and output the result next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide range labels, here is a generic formula

```
=INDEX([Range of your First Set of Data], Match([Range of the Name you are checking],0),4)
```

Range of yoour first set of data should be the first table you listed.
Range of the Name you are checking would be the cell adjacent to the field you are putting your value in.

I am using 4 as the last parameter because it matches the table you listed (4th column).